# SpringBoot gets an error “There is already controller bean method”, when two get or two post methods gets added in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'employeeController' method 
public java.util.List<com.test301.Test301.entity.Employee> com.test301.Test301.controller.EmployeeController.getLIstOfEmployees()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method
public com.test301.Test301.entity.Employee com.test301.Test301.controller.EmployeeController.getEmployeeById(java.lang.Integer) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test301.Test301.App.main(App.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'employeeController' method 
public java.util.List<com.test301.Test301.entity.Employee> com.test301.Test301.controller.EmployeeController.getLIstOfEmployees()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method
public com.test301.Test301.entity.Employee com.test301.Test301.controller.EmployeeController.getEmployeeById(java.lang.Integer) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:576) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:540) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:264) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:250) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:214) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:127) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Contoroller class

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.test301.Test301.controller;



import java.util.List;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.test301.Test301.entity.Employee;
import com.test301.Test301.service.IEmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private IEmployeeService empService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(name="/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return empService.addEmployee(emp);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(name="/getEmpList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Employee> getLIstOfEmployees(){
        return empService.getListOfEmployees();
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(name="/deleteEmployee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathParam("id") Integer empId) {
        return empService.deleteEmployee(empId);

    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(name="/getEmpById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathParam("id") Integer empId) {
        return empService.getEmployeeById(empId);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(name="/checkValidEmp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkValidEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return empService.checkValidEmployee(emp);
    }

}
```

Here i am getting an bean there is already 'employeeContoroller' bean method exist. When I have added one get & one post method it worked properly but when i have added one extra get method i am getting above error even if both the url are different.same for post method also, with one post method it worked properly but with two post method it showed error.

Comment: You are using `name` where you probably wanted to use `value` . Currently each get maps to the same URL.

Comment: And you further could probably use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` and then remove `@ResponseBody` from all methods too...

Comment: Thank You very much. It resolved my error.

Answer (score 11):

Change name with a path or value. [Details of name, path, value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--)

```
@RequestMapping(name="/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Correct:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple controllers let's say one Role has DeleteMapping with value = "delete" and in another controller for example named Person which also has DeleteMapping with value = "delete" , then you will have this error like in mine case. You can just change VELUE to something else and it will work